# Failed to transfer CELO on omni wallet using web3js

Tags: web3js, wallet-connect

I am able to connect omni wallet with wallet connect in my app. I want to transfer CELO to a blockchain address, when I request for a transaction, I am able to confirm the window on omni wallet and when I confirm the transaction, it shows success window on omni app, but transaction on blockchain didn't create and I am getting this error on the browser:

```
{success: false, error: 'could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.7.1)'}

Error: Failed to check for transaction receipt:
{
  "code": -32602,
  "message": "invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal non-string into Go value of type common.Hash"
}
```

Below is the code I am using to connect omni wallet using walletconnect:

```
  async function ConnectWallet() {
    try {
      provider = await EthereumProvider.init({
        projectId: 'xyz...',
        showQrModal: true,
        qrModalOptions: { themeMode: "light" },
        chains: [42220]
      });
      await provider.enable();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

And this is code I am using to send the transaction:

```
  async function SendTransaction() {
      const web3 = new Web3(provider);
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      web3.eth.sendTransaction({
        from: accounts[0],
        to: "0x5165dc9e9e57b5abb12bc79c419e0078d7b99116",
        value: parseEther("1").toString()
      })
        .on('transactionHash', function (hash) {
          console.log(hash);
        })
        .on('receipt', function (receipt) {
          console.log(receipt);
        })
        .on('confirmation', function (confirmationNumber, receipt) {
          console.log(confirmationNumber);
          console.log(receipt);
        })
        .on('error', function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }
```

The transaction confirm on omni wallet looks fine. Can somebody please tell me why am I getting this error?
[image]